# jqGrid group by same column name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Hi guys i would really apreciate helping me solving that problem.
I've tried to group those columns by the same name in one group and here's the result :

[image]

So what I want is to group the rows with the same name.

and here's my code

```
        autowidth: true,
        height:'auto',
        //overflow: 'auto',
        //autoheight: true,
        //max-height: 1000px,
        //forceFit:true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        grouping: (user.groupping != ''),
        groupingView: {
            groupField: [ ((user.groupping != '') ? user.groupping : 'name') ],
            groupColumnShow: [false],
            groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>'],
            groupCollapse: false,
            groupOrder: ['asc'],
            groupSummary: [true],
            groupDataSorted: true
        },
        footerrow: true,
```

Comment: It seems to me that your source data is not sorted by this condition. Depending on the conditions, your data should be sorted in two different way as in the condition **user.grouping** in groupField. This means that your data source should be sorted in this rule when it comes to the jqGrid. Hope your understand what I mean.

Comment: @TonyTomov Thanks for replying. Do you mean by sorting **asc** or **desc** so the grid can regoup by name ?

Comment: I mean that the data that come initially to the grid should be sorted in appropriate way. It seems to me it is not sorted correct. Please describe the version used or if possible prepare a demo or show us all the grid settings with simple data.